# Equinox circular dependency

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

I have Eclipse for JEE with Libra installed.
I have 3 OSGI(+Dynamic Web Module Facet) bundles in my Eclipse workspace. The first(let's name it CORE) imports the other 2(DB and MVC) + 3 more packs. DB imports apache-commons(CORE too), MVC has not any imports. All bundles i need are in the Target platform - Gemini, apache-commons, javax.*, etc. When I try to add all the 3 bundles into the Runtime just to start and test them there is [this problem](http://sitezone.eu/Capture.PNG).

In the MANIFEST these 2 packs do not import each others. When i try to add only the first bundle(CORE) to the Runtime eclipse crashes with stack overflow. In the server there are infinite dependencies in the DB and MVC bundles between them and i can not continue my work. When i remove the imports from the CORE I can add all 3 bundles without any problem and the runtime starts, CORE bundle is unusable(of course). I tried to create OSGI launcher. There everything works, but the problem is that Equinox OSGI Runtime can refresh(redeploy) my bundles without need to be restarted, but in the launcher i can not do this.

Any help?
Thanks.

EDIT: Some manifest properties

There are not plugins which require each other

***CORE manifest:***

```
Bundle-Name: org.proforge.bricks.core
Export-Package: org.proforge.bricks.core
Import-Package: org.apache.commons.configuration;version="1.10.0",
org.apache.commons.lang.exception;version="2.6.0",
org.osgi.framework;version="1.5.0",
 org.proforge.bricks.db,
 org.proforge.bricks.mvc
```

***DB manifest:***

```
Bundle-Name: org.proforge.bricks.db
Export-Package: org.proforge.bricks.db
Import-Package: org.apache.commons.configuration;version="1.10.0"
```

***MVC manifest:***

```
Bundle-Name: org.proforge.bricks.mvc
Export-Package: org.proforge.bricks.mvc
```

I put just export/import/name and miss the other properties

Comment: If two bundles both require each other, they should be made into one bundle.

Comment: ...or some parts need to be extracted to one or more new bundles.